# Angular UI Router - Compulsory URL parameter?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a couple of states the use the same controller. Some of these do not require a URL parameter while some do. How do I avoid a state from being accessible if the URL parameter is not provided?

Example:

I have 2 views or states, list and single. They both share the same controller. I have the routes mapped as follows:

```
state: app.list
url: /list
controller: appCtrl

state: app.single
url: /single/:id
controller: appCtrl
```

Now, I want `single` to be accessed only if the id is specified, other wise redirect to some other page. How is that possible using the same controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1**

You can use `$urlRouterProvider` with `when()` for redirection.

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // when there is an single route without param, redirect to /list
      $urlRouterProvider.when('/single/:id', ['$match', '$state', function($match, $state) {
          if($match.id === ""){
             $state.transitionTo("app.list");
          }
       }
      ]);
});
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/sEoUGGCEge0XbKp3nQnc?p=preview

**Approach 2**

You can check the `param` in `controller` side and redirect it to specific page

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($state, $stateParams) {
  if($state.current.name == 'app.single' && $stateParams.id === ""){
    $state.transitionTo("app.list");
  }
});
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QNF1RHy4Prde4CRhNLFa?p=preview

**Note:** In the above demos, redirection works when your current state should not be `app.single`. Means, State will not change if you are in `app.single` state and trying without param. So go to `main` page, then click the link `without param of single state`. it will redirect to `list` state.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems the function is never called!